# How to correctly type nested and the object indexing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an object which has set properties, one of which is custom that it self has properties that are a subset of the properties of the parent object. See below:

```
interface TFruit {
  weight: number;
  color: string;
  shape: 'round' | 'long' | 'oblong'
  custom: TCustom
}
 
interface TCustom {
  weight?: number;
  color?: string;
}
```

My goal is to create function that gets the value from custom if it’s not `undefined` otherwise it gets the value from the object. On top of that I want typescript to know the exact type of the returned value depending on the property passed in.

My current attempt is:

```
const getProperty = <TProperty extends keyof TCustom>(
  fruit: TFruit,
  property: TProperty
): TFruit['custom'][TProperty] extends undefined ? TFruit[TProperty] : TFruit['custom'][TProperty] => {
  const customProperty = fruit['custom'][property];
 
  if (customProperty !== undefined) {
    return customProperty;
  }
 
  return fruit[property];
}
```

`Type 'TCustom[TProperty] & {}' is not assignable to type 'TCustom[TProperty] extends undefined ? TFruit[TProperty] : TCustom[TProperty]'.ts(2322)`

[image]

TLDR; how do I correctly type the function I’ve created, so typescript knows the type of the return value.

Comment: If you redefine `TCustom` to be `Pick`ed from `TFruit` your current definition has no errors. `type TCustom = Pick<TFruit, "weight" | "color">;`. Your current implementation doesn't provide typescript an explicit overlap of TCustom and TFruit